# SharePoint: Can I create different navigation bars for different pages?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online

I'm new here. I'm working on a SharePoint website and I want to create a different navigation bar for a part of pages while others use the global navigation bar. It is like they are different websites but actually they are not. I wonder is that possible? If it is, how can I make it?

In addition, according to my research, it's possible to have a different navigation bar if I create a subsite, right?

The problem now is that I don't have the permission to create a subsite, that's why I'm asking if I can create a different navigation bar for a set of pages.

Thank you!

Comment: I want to clarify my question by providing more details. I'm using SharePoint Server 2013 and I'm asking about the global navigation. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For a SharePoint site, there are two sets of navigation. 
One: Global Navigation.
 Two: Site Navigation (Which is mostly the sites Left side navigation)
These articles describes more about having multiple navigation elements in a site: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee695757.aspx 
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/customize-the-navigation-on-your-sharepoint-site-3cd61ae7-a9ed-4e1e-bf6d-4655f0bf25ca

Note: Instructions vary based on your SharePoint environment and setup. For better understanding if you can share which version of SharePoint you are working on. can give more insights. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I would ask is that possible to have different global navigation bars on the same site? (I'm using SharePoint Server 2013) Thank you!

Comment: @Lindsey There can be only one Global Navigation per site. you can break sub-site inheritance and have different global navigation for each site under one site collection. Hope This helps.